# try, except, finally in a loop with continue python

Tags: python

Everyone.
Recently I have encountered a problem that confuses me a lot. 
I know that in python try and except relation and finally will be executed no matter what. 
But what if I put try, except and finally in a for loop and add a continue inside except block, will finally block be executed still?

For example,

```
for _ in something:
    try:
        mycode
    except:
        mycode
        continue
    finally:
        mycode
```

Thank you all for the answer

Comment: Have you tried running that?

Comment: Yes. `finally` is executed *no matter what*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As @chepner said, `finally` is executed *no matter what.*